# command prompt returning blank when I give command of python

Tags: python-3.8

I am using windows 10 OS.

nothing appears when I type python on cmd

```
C:\Users\username>python

C:\Users\username>
```

but it does when I type `py`

```
C:\Users\username>py

Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

and also when I try to open any python file directly it fails to open it.